# How to get the text from the <text> tag using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I cant able to get text from the Web Element on below mentioned tags:

```
<text dy="-.1em" class="c3-gauge-value" transform="" style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle; pointer-events: none; font-size: 9px;">95</text>
```

Need to get the value "95", that value will available inside the **donot** chart.

I am facing issue :

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
selector","selector":"#chart > svg > g:nth-child(2) > g.c3-chart >
g.c3-chart-arcs > g > text"}
```

Anyone can you provide any solutions.

Comment: "<text dy="-.1em" class="c3-gauge-value" transform="" style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle; pointer-events: none; font-size: 9px;">95</text>"

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML block and the language you are using

Comment: may be you need to wait for the text to be appeared. Also, check for the element is inside a frame or not.

Comment: What did you try? Relevant html code please.

Comment: add the language tag. and share the HTML , I suspect SVG in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try xPath to locate your element:

```
//text[@dy = '-.1em' and @class='c3-gauge-value']
```

Btw it's probably necessary to add `wait` method to wait until element will be attached to DOM. Also make sure that your element is not in the `iframe`.

I don't know which language are you using, thats why I cannot provide the concrete example code for your case. But you can search on this site, there are many very good examples.

Comment: What is the use of getting text `95` by hard coding `95` in the locator :D. Question is missing the required details.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it's text by,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".c3-gauge-value")).getText();
```